# Reducing Size of Tikz-QTree

Tags: linguistics, tikz-qtree, qtree

Only about half of the following tree shows up on my screen, but there is a tonnnnn of white space. Is there any way for me to reduce this and change the length of some of the lines in order for it to fit fully? Thank you!

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

Paragraph paragraph paragraph

\Tree [.Proto-Siouan [.Western [.MissouriValley Crow Hidatsa ] [.*Mandan ] [.OhioValley *Tutelo [ *Ofo *Biloxi ] ] [.MississippiValley [.Dakotan [.Nakota Stoney Assiniboine ] [.``Sioux" Lakhota [ Dakota Nakota ] ] ] [ [.Winnebago-Chiwere [.Hocank ] [.Chiwere [.*Iowa ] [.*Oto ] ] ] [.Dhegiha *Kansa-Osage [ *Quapaw Omaha-Ponca ] ] ] ] ] [.Eastern *Catawba *Woccon ] ]

Paragraph paragraph paragraph

\end{document}
```

Comment: please see the answer below -- does it look better now -- some more fine tuning is off course required

Comment: @jsbibra Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For growing down is your tree to wide. Try to make it grow to right, reduce font size and enable split long names into two lines:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

Paragraph paragraph paragraph
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{grow=right,level distance=24mm}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=left, font=\footnotesize, anchor=west}}

\Tree 
[.Proto--\\Siouan 
    [.Western 
        [.Missouri-\\Valley Crow Hidatsa ] 
        [.*Mandan ] 
        [.OhioValley *Tutelo 
            [ *Ofo *Biloxi ] 
        ] 
        [.Mississippi-\\Valley 
            [.Dakotan 
                [.Nakota Stoney Assiniboine ] 
                [.``Sioux" Lakhota 
                    [ Dakota Nakota ] 
                ] 
            ] 
            [ 
                [.Winnebago--\\Chiwere 
                    [.Hocank ] 
                    [.Chiwere 
                        [.*Iowa ] 
                        [.*Oto ] 
                    ] 
                ] 
                [.Dhegiha *Kansa--\\Osage 
                    [ *Quapaw Omaha--\\Ponca ] 
                ] 
            ] 
        ] 
    ] 
    [.Eastern *Catawba *Woccon ] 
]
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
Paragraph paragraph paragraph

\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

Comment: This is perfect. Saved my life. Thank you!!!

Comment: @Noah, you are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone} 
\usepackage[edges]{forest} 
\usetikzlibrary{fit} 
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\begin{document} 
    \begin{forest} 
        for tree={
                    grow'=0, 
                    align=center,
                    draw, 
%                   fill=white, 
%                   blur shadow,
                    forked edges,
        },
        [.Proto-Siouan [
        .Western [
        .MissouriValley Crow Hidatsa ] 
        [.*Mandan ] 
        [.OhioValley *Tutelo [ 
        *Ofo *Biloxi ] ] 
        [.MississippiValley [
        .Dakotan [
        .Nakota Stoney Assiniboine ] 
        [.``Sioux" Lakhota [ 
        Dakota Nakota ] ] ] 
        [ [.Winnebago-Chiwere [
        .Hocank ] 
        [.Chiwere [
        .*Iowa ] 
        [.*Oto ] ] ] 
        [.Dhegiha *Kansa-Osage [ 
        *Quapaw Omaha-Ponca ] ] ] ] ] 
        [.Eastern *Catawba *Woccon ] ]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, too! Thank you!